# how do i make my text stick to the right of the screen for all screen sizes

Tags: css

I'm trying to make my navbar stick to the right of the screen phone screen sizes of tablets and bigger but what ever i do it isnt working could someone please help me out as i am new to this and it is for a project that is due in 2 days.

```css
/*Google Fonts*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,700;1,900&family=Pacifico&display=swap');

/*wildcard selector*/

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/*General Styles*/

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*Generic project styles*/
  color: #3a3a3a;
  font-family: "lato", sans-serif;
}


/*header*/

header {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #3a3a3a;
  display: flex;
}

header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "pacifico", sans-serif;
  color: #252525;
}

#menu {
  font-size: 110%;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#menu li {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.active {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #3a3a3a;
}


/*Navbar styles with dropdown toggle*/

nav {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #3a3a3a;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: baseline;
  top: 100%;
}


/*nav toggle*/

#nav-toggle:checked~nav {
  display: block;
}

#nav-toggle {
  display: none;
}

#nav-toggle-label {
  font-size: 2rem;
}


/*Main*/

main {
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}


/*Footer*/

footer {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}


/* Media query: tablets and larger (768px and up) */

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  /* Header */
  nav {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: none;
    width: fit-content;
    padding-top: 1rem;
  }
  #menu {
    display: flex;
    float: right;
  }
  #menu>li {
    padding-left: 1rem;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  #nav-toggle-label {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<!--Header-->
<header>
  <a href="index.html">
    <h1 id="logo">Ben's Chess Club</h1>
  </a>
  <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle" name="nav-toggle">
  <label for="nav-toggle" id="nav-toggle-label">X</label>
  <nav>
    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="" class="active">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sign Up</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<!--Main-->
<main>Main</main>

<!--Footer-->
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Comment: In your media query you're missing a closing `}`

Answer (score 4):

One quick fix, would be to add `justify-content: space-between;` to the header styles, below `display: flex;`, as by default `display:flex` align its children in a row, from left.

```
header {
  ...
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

And if you want to have the close tag `X` vertically centered, just add `align-items: center`.

```
header {
  ...
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```